# Вставка изображений в элементы

Tags: java, android, android-studio, изображения, android-drawable

В общем, такая задача: нужно поместить изображения больших размеров в `drawable` или `mipmap`(`assets` не нужно). Чтобы получать его через `R.drawable.image` или `getDrawable(R.drawable.image)`. Когда вставляю их в проект через `Android Studio` ,он их режет, и после на экране они мутные. Как исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте просто копирнуть файлы в нужные папки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тоесть хотите сказать что разделенные папки по xhdpi - xxhdpi ...Можно вручную не обрезав закинуть больши фотки и ниче не будет? при этом ниче не будет если размеры одинаковы?

Comment: Я просто предположил, что вы какой-то плагин используете и он всё портит. Если вы по папкам руками всё раскладываете, то всё должно работать. В этом случае, возможно, дело не в картинках, а в том, как вы их отображаете. В общем, нужно много подробностей

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ок спс за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам сможет помочь [Android Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer).